# Delete from django database with many form in same template

Tags: javascript, django, database

I am new to django and I'm trying to build a to do list
so what I click on "✓" button it turn the item to green from red using javascript
and now Iam trying to make the button "X" delete objects from the django database
so I stuck here
this is my code I am waiting for your help

my views

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import *
from .forms import *
# Create your views here.


def index(request):
    tasks = Task.objects.all()
    form = TaskForm()

    if request.method == "POST" :
        form = TaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect("/")
    context = {
        'tasks' : tasks , 'form' : form
    }
    return render(request,"tasks/list.html", context)


    def deletetask(request, pk):
        if request.method == "POST" and "delete" in request.POST:
            print(request.POST)
            print("good work")
            item = request.POST.get(id=pk)
            Task.objects.delete(id=item)
        return render(request,"tasks/list.html")
```

my forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm

from .models import *


class TaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = '__all__'
```

my models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    creted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

my template

```
    <h3>Hello world from templates</h3>

<form action="/" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
    
    {{form.title}}
    <input type="submit" name="Ajout medoc">
</form>


{% for task in tasks %}
    <div >
        <form action="/" method="POST">
        <p style="color: red" id="{{task.id}}">
            <input type="button" name="cmd" value="✓" onclick="document.getElementById( '{{ task.id }}').style.color = 'green'"> 
            
            <input type="button" name="delete" value="X" id="{{task.id}}">
            
        {{ task }}
        </p>
        </form>
        
    </div>

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

What i would do instead is this:

```
def deletetask(request, pk):
    instance = Task.objects.delete(id=pk)
    instance.delete()
     
    return redirect('index')
```

and then in your template:

```
{% for task in tasks %}
<div >
    <p style="color: red" id="{{task.id}}">
        <input type="button" name="cmd" value="✓" onclick="document.getElementById( '{{ task.id }}').style.color = 'green'"> 
        
        <a href="{% url 'delete_item' task.id %}">
             <button>X</button>
        </a>
        
    {{ task }}
    </p>
    
</div>
```

{% endfor %}

In your urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
   path("delete_item/", views.delete_item, name="delete_item"),

]
```

The code in the template is calling a function from a "a" html tag instead of using a form.

Comment: Sorry my bad.
Change the view so it look like this:
def deletetask(request, pk):
    instance = Task.objects.get(id=pk)
    instance.delete()
     
    return redirect('index')